# Google Meet Microphone issues, "Helium" Voice

Tags: sound, microphone

I started to have very strange issues when using Google Meet Video Calls.
It worked for one day but on the next day (after I used Google Hangouts Video Call for the first time) it started to show the following very strange audio issues.

I can hear others well but others hear my voice as if I inhaled Helium, so for them it seems that I have a high pitched voice.
This is no joke!
I have this problem since 2 days and it didnt went away so far.

When I am using the same account on my MacBook, Meet works as expected.

Anybody knows what can be the problem here?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt solve the problem, it seemed to be related to the onboard sound card drivers.
I bought a new sound card, now it works.